# Selenium Webdriver "Мягкая проверка"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Есть некий код.

```
@Test
public void TestName(){
Действие;
Aseer.assertTrue;
Действие;
Aseer.assertTrue
Действие;
Aseer.assertTrue
}
```

И так далее. 
Можно ли сделать так что бы тест не падал при неверном ожидаемом результате после каждого `Aseer.assertTrue`, а заканчивал свою работу в любом случае и позже просто выводил бы какую-нибудь `VerifyException` ?

Comment: а чем отличается "падать при неверном результате" и "заканчивать работу с VerifyException" ?

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Имелось ввиду, что в одном тесте выполняется сразу несколько проверок. И нужно что бы тест выполнил их все, даже если первый ожидаемый результат с фактическим не совпал

Comment: Это неправильный подход. Вашим действием может быть изменение чего-либо в системе, и вы будете ожидать, что дальше у вас будут эти изменения будут. А у вас их не будет => такой подход плохой.

Comment: Что, простите? Каким образом я что-то могу изменить в системе?

Comment: При нажатии на какую либо кнопку, у тебя происходит переход на другую страницу, в которой ты должен проверить некоторые вещи. Кнопка не нажалась => нельзя проверить состояние другой страницы => при фейле нет смысла дальше что-либо проверять. Пример абстрактный

Comment: Ну а если. к примеру, нужно проверить на странице наличие 20 разных элементов. Первый отсутствует, тест падает, наличие остальных уже не проверяется. Или нужно каждый шаг в отдельный тест оформлять?

Answer (score -1):

Если проверяете динамические данные, т.е. последствия каких-то действий, то каждую проверку лучше разнести в отдельный тест. Если статику, т.е. просто несколько проверок на одной странице, без действий между ними, то выносите эти проверки в отдельную функцию. А в тесте уже делаете "ассерт" этой функции. Сама же функция проверок сверяет все необходимые данные и на выходе предоставляет либо "ок", либо список найденных ошибок.

В любом случае есть неплохое правило, которое я стараюсь придерживаться, - один тест, один "ассерт".